# Replicate bitcoin core for backup

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, backup

I want to know if possible to have the same bitcoin core and his same wallet running at the same time in two different machines, can I use the same RPC user/pass, I have o machine running but I want to have a backup running in case the main is offline then I can switch to the second one and can send/receive bitcoins in the same wallet is used by both, that's possible? how can I do that? I will appreciate your help. regards.

Answer (score 1):

The source of truth will always be the blockchain, so I think you just need to run your software on two different machines, with both of them referring to the same wallet, address, etc. An action by one should be reflected by the other.